# Update Salesforce Object & fields using Data extension in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have recently connected our orgs using Marketing Cloud Connect.

I have a Cloud page with a smartcapture form which sends values into a DE once it is submitted.
I have 15 form values that are being captured in this DE however I want only 5 of them to update an Object in Salesforce. These are all known subscribers.

What is the recommended way to do this?

1. Can this be achieved using Journey builder? i.e. entry source becomes the DE and then **Update Object** activity.
   If yes, Can I map the DE attribute with the Object field in Salesforce?
   Does this need any configuring in Salesforce?
2. is there any other way to do this?
   Just looking for some high level direction. Id appreciate advice on this. Regards

Comment: Have you looked at the salesforce ampscript functions ?

Comment: ah yes that i thought would be my last resort as i am not from a coding background. Would that be UpdateSalesforceObject function to pass the 5 x values into their respective fields in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the described use case I would use Update Object activity. It allows you to map fields easily. You just need to make sure that SF object is available to you.

Comment: Yup that is exactly what i did and it works fine.